# where to locate common files in a django project

Tags: django

I'm working with Django and I'm starting to refactor the templates and have some questions. If I'm using jquery in different applications in the same project, where should I put the jquery file? I've tried to create a static folder in the project directory but didn't work, I'm not sure that is a good practice to copy the file in each app I have under the same project. The same with styles, if I have a .css file with general styles, which needs to be applied to all templates in every app, where I'm supposed to put this file? I guess it should be only in one place, and then every app use that.

Another question, if I'm using header and footer templates, should I have those two files for each app I have? or can I have just two files for all the apps in the project?

thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_DIRS) to specify *additional* directories in which to look for static files.

In a project of mine I set it to look in `build/static-build`, which is a directory generated by `make` from project-specific files in a top-level directory called `static-src` which contains things like a global CSS file that applies to all pages, plus external libraries like jQuery, Bootstrap, and so on.